# Convert a genetic optimiser into a Driver

Tags: openmdao

I already have my component with the function I want to optimise. However, OpenMDAO Alpha 1.0 does not contain (to my knowledge) a wrapper for a genetic optimiser. I have written my own, and would now like to make it a Driver. I am a bit lost here, can I ask for any guidance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that OpenMDAO doesn't have a genetic optimizer yet. You could use NSGAII from the pyopt library, but since you have one you want to use, writing your own driver should be fairly straightforward. The easiest example to follow would be our [scipy wrapper](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/master/openmdao/drivers/scipy_optimizer.py) for its optimizers. Your wrapper would have to look something like this:

```
from openmdao.core.driver import Driver

class GeneticOptimizer(Driver):

    def __init__(self):
        super(GeneticOptimizer, self).__init__()

        #some stuff to setup your genetic optimizer here

    def run(self, problem):
        """function called to kick off the optimization

        Args
        ----
        problem : `Problem`
            Our parent `Problem`.

        """

        #NOTE: you'll use these functions to build your optimizer
        #to execute the model
        problem.root.solve_nonlinear()

        #function to set values to the design variables
        self.set_param(var_name, value)
```

Comment: I have a similar question:  are there any plans to add other optimization packages other than Scipy to evaluate other problem types -- global, stochastic, non-linear, multi-objective, etc.?  There are other fantastic packages out there, such as PyGMO (http://esa.github.io/pygmo/),  that have an extensive algorithm library that would be great to leverage.

Comment: We have a wrapper built in for pyopt_sparse (https://bitbucket.org/mdolab/pyoptsparse), which has a number of other optimization routines. We're open to including just about anything in the library, but our own research isn't heavily focused on gradient free methods right now, so its just not a high priority. A wrapper to PyGMO would be a welcome pull request though!